# How to display both phone number and name on yealink screen from twilio programmable voice?

Tags: twilio-twiml

During incoming call either phone number or name only displayed on yealink screen, for example if caller name (CNAM) passes from Twiml, it sends to FROM field, not name or passes phone number both to FROM field and NAME, expected that name and phone number both can be displayed on the screen.
[Yealink screen when displays phone number in both fields (both lines)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CBq6.jpg)

Twilio support offered to use custom headers or UUI to pass the value in CallerName parameter to the SIP phone https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011213347-Passing-Custom-Information-via-Requests-to-Twilio

Yealink documentation provides that we can pass CNAM (or any other name/value) with FROM header to device screen.

```
Caller ID source = FROM
The IP phone checks Privacy: id header preferentially, if there is a Privacy: id in the INVITE request, the calling line identification information will be hidden and the IP phone LCD screen presents anonymous.
If there is not any Privacy: id header in the INVITE request, the IP phone checks and presents the caller identification from the 'P-Preferred-Identity header'. 
If there is not 'P-Preferred-Identity' header in the INVITE request, the IP phone presents the caller identification derived from the FROM header.
```

[How yealink accepts FROM field.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k3vK.png)

[I set up in yealink settings to accept FROM parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDyef.png) and test it with following TWIML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Dial>
    <Sip>
        sip:100@test.sip.us1.twilio.com?x-FROM=test
    </Sip>
</Dial>
</Response>
```

or this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Dial>
    <Sip>
        sip:100@test.sip.us1.twilio.com?FROM=test
    </Sip>
</Dial>
</Response>
```

With these TWIMLs yealink ignores SIP headers and passes phone number to both lines, tried many different types of SIP headers to pass to caller name with phone number to yealink screen, but none of them worked.

Which SIP headers or yealink settings do I need to use to pass name and phone number to yealink screen from twilio programmable voice?

Comment: Silly thing, but I note that in the header you used a lowercase `x` to set the header. The [docs and examples](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011213347-Passing-Custom-Information-via-Requests-to-Twilio) show an uppercase `X`. Can you try like that? Also, are you able to confirm that the yealink is receiving the headers?

Comment: @philnash Hello, thanks for response I tried
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Dial>
    <Sip>
        sip:101@test.sip.us1.twilio.com?X-from=test
    </Sip>
</Dial>
</Response>'

'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Dial>
    <Sip>
        sip:101@test.sip.us1.twilio.com?X-FROM=test
    </Sip>
</Dial>
</Response>'

'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Dial>
    <Sip>
        sip:101@test.sip.us1.twilio.com?X-NAME=test
    </Sip>
</Dial>
</Response>'
Still only phone numbers displayed

Comment: @philnash here the image link of yealink screen https://drive.google.com/file/d/16RYku2JaPxBLNllWmsFghdaVzcTuJcNP/view?usp=sharing  and yealink documentation says that accepts SIP header - FROM  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1874VxadvDUa7H65yhVsRyqleMy9tTm2f/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you see the logs of the SIP requests from Twilio to your device? It would be good to confirm that the `X-FROM` header is being sent.